# Erroneous "question put on hold since you loaded page" prevents flagging

Tags: bug, flags, on-hold, flag-dialog

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640540/how-to-configure-connection-timeout-in-hibernate?noredirect=1&lq=1):

1. I visited the question.
2. I closed it as a dupe.
3. I attempted to also flag it with a merge request.
4. I was met with an error saying that the question was put on hold since I loaded the page, which is strange because I've gone through the *close → immediate flag* sequence many, many times in the past with no issue.
5. I reloaded the page.
6. I continued to be met with the same error, which seems broken since I've reloaded the page since it was put on hold.

Here is a video showing *reload → flag* attempt (yellow circle indicates mouse click):

[image]

Browser is Chrome 52.0.2743.116 on Windows 7.

PS: I re-opened that question because I realized it was subtly different. Just... don't worry about that.

Comment: That must be related with [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283925/answers-disappear-briefly-then-reload-when-i-click-them)

Comment: @rene It crossed my mind but... who knows. I can at least tell you that both reports boil down to me being way too excited about this animated gif screen recorder.

Comment: Seen that a while ago, but the flag dialog can be opened about two minutes after the question is closed. I assumed it's some kind of weird grace period in which one isn't allowed to flag. And it was fully reproduced for every question I closed. (Think it was couple of weeks ago.)